# Why is there a passport control in Västerås airport coming from Spain?

Tags: schengen, passports

I (Spanish national) arrived in Västerås airport (BTW calling this Stockholm is a joke) from Málaga. Both Sweden and Spain are in Schengen, so why did we go through a passport control? I thought this was something Corona-related, but it is strange since all travel bans into Sweden have been removed, even from outside Schengen.

Comment: The airport could simply be too small to maintain separate Schengen and non-Schengen area. Since it's also serving flights to London, it's easier to treat everybody as coming from outside the Schengen area. How did it look like? Was the flow of passengers from your plane mixed with other passengers? Was there anything that looks like a Schengen part of the terminal?

Comment: @Relaxed There is a couple of daily flights separated by eight hours, so no, there is no mix of passengers.

Comment: You could also have taken a wrong turn… not all airports are perfectly separating Schengen from non-Schengen arrivals. I once managed to get lost in a major Schengen airport, arriving from the US, and ending at my intra-Schengen departure gate, without anyone seeing any ID at all.

Comment: @Aganju No. Västerås Airport has only 7 weekly arrivals, 3 from Stanstead (non Schengen) and 4 from Spain (Schengen). All arrivals are several hours apart, each arriving plane departs back to its origin about 30 minutes after arrival and the airport itself only opens around each arrival and departure. The immigration checkpoint will only be staffed on demand and not permanently. If immigration check was performed when a plane arrived from Spain, it is obviously on purpose and not a mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Schengen works the same - but in the UK you go through a passport control whenever you go through the airfield security. For example, my father was going to have a tour of a plane (can't recall if it was a Lancaster bomber or the Vulcan). The plane wasn't even going to move - he couldn't go because he didn't have an in-date passport. Was it a passport check or actual customs checks? There's a relatively big difference between the two - a passport check is more just checking ID.

Comment: Landing in Arlanda (the main airport in Stockholm) from Spain I also regularly have to go through passport checks, so it isn't being a small airport or taking a wrong turn.

Answer (score 18):

There are not supposed to be any *routine* immigration checks at the borders between Schengen countries, but for many years that has been more a theory than reality. Several countries introduced temporary regular immigration checks during the refugee 'crisis' in 2015 and this 'temporarity' is in many places still ongoing. Then came corona and was used as an argument for border checks and now we have the flow of refugees from Ukraine.

Short summary: You are and have never been guaranteed to not be controlled when crossing an intra Schengen border. Many Schengen countries also require by law that you carry valid travel documents with you when you cross their borders even if you come from or leave to another Schengen country.

Comment: About "valid travel documents", to make things worse, a Spanish ID card is seen somewhat awkwardly abroad. To carry an electronically readable passport (and the kindness of the Swedish policeman) has avoided me some hassle..

Comment: @Miguel Why do you think that kindness of the Swedish police officer avoided you hassle? In any case, a Spanish national id card would of course also have been plenty enough to enter Sweden. It is considered a valid travel document at least throughout the entire EEA and also in several other countries.